# Jobs recent searches is truncating unnecessarily

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

With the recent UI updates to Jobs, the Recent Searches has started truncating search strings, even when there is room left in the box to expand the string.

[image: Unused whitespace]

The highlighted search strings are for two different searches. One is looking for only remote positions with a salary over 100K. The other is looking for remote positions, or relocation available positions, with a salary over 100K. With the truncation, it's not possible to tell which is which.

Please expand the string to fill the available space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue. It should be fixed now.